# Antiderivatives

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have this definite integral and I need to find its derivative with respect to $t$. I am not sure how to do it without computing the value of the integral and taking its derivative.
$$\int_2^t \sqrt{u^4-16}\;du$$

Comment: Maybe use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: Using lulu's hint, you easily get the result $\sqrt{t^4-16}$

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I see.

Answer (score 2):

Apply Fundamental theorem of Calculus here. Let's define $$f(t)=\int_0^t\sqrt{u^4-16} du.$$
Then $f'(t)=\sqrt{t^4-16}$.

Comment: Thank you. I see now.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that in general

$$f(t)=\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}g(u) du\implies f'(t)=g(b(t))\cdot b'(t)-g(a(t))\cdot a'(t)$$